# nginx only serves php located in the root

Tags: nginx, mac-osx, php-fpm

I have the following file paths

```
http://localhost/test.php
http://localhost/playground/server.php
```

Both of them simple hold

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The issue is, nginx will serve the first one, but the one nested under the playground folder
it will simply trigger a downloading event in my browser.. what the heck??

Here is my server block:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name localhost;

  root   /var/www;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    autoindex on;
    index     index.html index.htm;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Edit fastcfgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME      $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO                    $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is inside of your `/usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params` (include that with your question next time, otherwise we're just guessing over here) with `fastcgi_param` to be exact, try replacing it with:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: The issue was resolved by simply renaming server.php to anything. something with the file name is causing the download..

Comment: @elad.chen interesting.. what was the error message you were getting inside of your logs while it was `server.php`?

Comment: The logs didn't show any error, just the get request was logged. you seem interested in this behavior as do I. I have attached my fastcgi_params

Comment: @elad.chen how about attaching relevant entries from `error_log` too?)